# pgAdmin version not matching after installation

Tags: windows, pgadmin-4

I am using Windows 10 Professional.
I downloaded **postgresql-13.1-1-windows-x64** from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

After successful installation, when opening pgAdmin for the first time, I get popup

> You are currently running 4.28 of pgAdmin, however the current version is 4.30.

I cannot close the popup and pgAdmin continuously displays spinner and the words "Loading pgAdmin 4 v4.28". I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For Window 10 Professional and postgres 13.1.1, I was able to download pgAdmin 4.30 from the pgAdmin website at https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/.
Installing the download overwrote 4.28, and I was able to open pgAdmin s4.30 uccessfully.